# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when updating table

Tags: vb.net, oracle

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

cmd = New OleDbCommand(
    "update sales set outlet_no=' " & tb1.Text & _
    " 'and eid=' " & tb2.Text & _
    " 'and cid=' " & TB3.Text & _
    " 'and pid=' " & TB4.Text & _
    " 'and sale_date=' " & TB5.Text & _
    " 'and quantity=' " & TB6.Text & _
    " 'where outlet_no=' " & tb1.Text & " ' ", conn)**

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I have checked 100 times and i find the syntax of UPDATE correct.Please help. I need this fixed soon for a project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct `UPDATE` statement syntax is:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ..., colN = valN
WHERE somecolumn = somevalue
```

But you currently have it as:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2 AND ... AND colN = valN
WHERE somecolumn = somevalue
```

The problem are the `AND` keywords.  They should be commas (`,`).

---

By the way, I'll say it now, and you'll hear everyone else saying it.  Please consider using parameter binding instead of concatenating your values directly in the SQL the way you are doing.  One reason is to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.  But it also prevents breaking your query if any of your values has a single quote in it, and you forget to double the single quote.

**EDIT**

And now that `T.S.` has so kindly cleaned up the formatting of your question, it's also apparent to me that, even after you fix the general syntax of your `UPDATE` statement, you may find that it doesn't do quite what you are expecting, because you seem to have undesired extra spaces within your single quotes. (e.g.: `outlet_no=' "`, or `& " ' "`).

Yet another reason to use parameter binding: you won't have to worry about the placement of single quotes.